# Obtener la hipotenusa a partir de 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, botón, function, parametros

Necesito sacar la hipotenusa donde me ingresen los valores necesarios y que me genere el resultado mediante un alert pero no he podido, tengo este código que me sirve la sacad de hipotenusa pero si yo mismo en el código le ingreso lo valores necesarios no me deja que en la página el usuario lo ingrese

```js
function Hipotenusa() {
    var control = document.getElementById("A").value;
    var control = document.getElementById("B").vale;
    var dms = new Date(control);
    alert("la Hipotenusa es: "+dms);

    if(typeof A != 'number' || typeof B != "number"){
        return null;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(A, 2) + Math.pow(B, 2));
}
```

```html
<h4 class="title1">SACA LA HIPOTENUSA DE UN TRIANGULO </h4>
<h6>Nesecitaremos el catetoA y catetoB</h6>
<img src="img/descarga.png" alt="8">


<p>CATETO A<input type="text" id="A" ></p>
<p>CATETO B<input type="text" id="B"></p>
<input type="button" onclick="Hipotenusa()" value="CALCULAR">
```

Comment: Dejen de cambiar la publicación. Ahora mi respuesta está obsoleta. Igual la voy a dejar ahí.

Comment: @Cuauhtli En que cambia tu respuesta con mi edición?

Comment: El estilo. Antes de cambiar la pregunta, tanto pregunta y respuesta estaban en el mismo estilo, luego ya no y ambos estilos difieren. Mi respuesta se ve enmarañada porque la pregunta original así estaba. Luego de cambiada la pregunta, ahora mi respuesta se nota enmarañada casi a proposito, jajaja

Comment: Dejala así. Igual el código de la pregunta está bien extraño aunque le apliques patrones de diseño, SOLID, Design Patterns.

Comment: @Cuauhtli Mil disculpas, es que me gusta presionar el botón copiar a respuesta :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta declarando cada variable según el lado.

También, no estas sacando la hipotenusa con `Date()`, además de que cuando sacas el valor del ladoB, tienes un typo porque pones `.vale` en lugar de `value`.

Como sugerencia, trata de nombrar tus variables con nombres descriptivos. Esto te salvará en toda tu carrera como programador.

Tu código (antes de que lo editaran) te debería de quedar algo así:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>EJERCICIOS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4 class="title1">SACA LA HIPOTENUSA DE UN TRIANGULO</h4>
    <h6>Nesecitaremos el catetoA y catetoB</h6>
    <img src="img/descarga.png" alt="8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function hipotenusa() {
        var ladoA = document.getElementById("A").value;
        var ladoB = document.getElementById("B").value;

        if(isNaN(ladoA) || isNaN(ladoB)) {
            return null;
        }

        var hipotenusa = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ladoA, 2) + Math.pow(ladoB, 2));
        
        alert("la Hipotenusa es: " + hipotenusa);
    }
    </script>
    <p>CATETO A<input type="text" id="A"></p>
    <p>CATETO B<input type="text" id="B"></p>
    <input type="button" onclick="hipotenusa()" value="CALCULAR">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muhas gracia quedo exelente ; )